# Formula for the root of $x^2=-3\mod n$ when $n=p_1^{k_1}\cdots p_l^{k_l}$ and $p_i$ primes equal to $1\mod 3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Consider the equation $$x^2=-3\mod n,$$ where $n=p_1^{k_1}\cdots p_l^{k_l}$ with $p_i$ primes equal to $1\mod 3$. Notice that any such $n$ can written as $a^2+3b^2$ (by a theorem of Fermat) for some integers $a,b$ such that exactly one is odd.

My question: does there exist a general formula for the roots to this equation in terms of $n$?

What I have in mind is best illustrated by the following example. Consider the case $a=1$, $b=2c$. In this case, $$n=1+12c^2,$$ and a root to the equation is then given by $$x=6c.$$
My question then is whether for more general $n=a^2+3b^2$ there exists an expression for a root $x$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: If $b$ is coprime with $n$, you can take $x\equiv a/b\pmod n$.

Comment: @FabioLucchini Thank you for your answer, I see that this is indeed a solution. However, it seems that the simultaneous occurrence of both $b$ coprime with $n$ and $a$ divisible by $b$ only exists when $b=1$. I checked this for $n<10000$. If this is indeed true for any $n$, then the roots you describe are $x=a$ for $n=a^2+3$, $a$ even.

Comment: Note that the solution $x\equiv a/b\pmod n$ holds also when $a$ is not divisible by $b$, because $b$ is invertible modulo $n$.

Comment: @FabioLucchini Aha, I understand now. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @FabioLucchini I have a follow up question: ideally I would like a manifestly integral expression for $x$. The solution which you give requires one to invert $b$. I was wondering if perhaps there exists an expression for $b^{-1}$ in terms of $a,b,n$ which is manifestly integral.

Comment: yes, $b^{-1}\equiv b^{\varphi(n)-1}\pmod n$ by Euler's theorem.

Comment: @FabioLucchini Thanks so much for all the replies. Your answer gives me one more question: do you know if there exists an explicit expression of $\phi(n)$ in terms of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: you can write $\varphi(n)$ in term of $p_i$ and $k_i$, but I don't if also in terms of $a$ and $b$.